# How to find Exterior wall facing south-east, south-west, north-east, north-west in C# Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api, autodesk-bim360, bim

I need to find "exterior wall facing" in c# revit API...please help me. I want the wall facing.. the wall is in which facing like southEast, southwest, northeast, northwest.
I have referred this link
https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/south-facing-walls.html

i have use the math.abs(AngleToSouth) * 57.2958=angle in degree
57.2958 is redian
but not getting
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please always perform some minimal research before asking a question.

One of the places to look for answers to Revit API questions is in the sample collection included with the Revit SDK.

In this case, the sample `DirectionCalculation` demonstrates exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: yes sir i refer DirectionCalculation it is more useful for me..thank you

Comment: Great! glad to hear it helped. Please upvote my answer then, to make it easier for others to find as well.